# Dynamic Styles in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Given the following snippets of HTML, CSS, and Vue code I would like to be able to construct a series of CSS style classes dynamically using a computed property in Vue 2 and bind them to the span that already has a class of panel-icon. As seen in the CSS snippet, the class name should be in the form of .icon--toolname where toolname is grabbed from the toolName property in the JSON. When I try to save the results of the for loop to a variable and return that variable I get only one result, instead of the four that I am expecting. The overall idea is that the CSS icon-- class should match the tool name that is being displayed via the v-for loop.

HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="lab">
    <a class="panel-block" v-for="tool in tools">
        <span class="panel-icon" :class="style">
            <i class="fas fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
        {{ tool.toolName }}
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.icon--bulma {
    color: hsl(171, 100%, 41%);
}

.icon--jgthms {
    color: hsl(204, 86%, 53%);
}

.icon--marksheet {
    color: hsl(48, 100%, 67%);
}

.icon--minireset {
    color: hsl(348, 100%, 61%);
}
```

Vue.js:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#lab',
    data: {
        tools: [
            {
                toolName: 'bulma'
            },
            {
                toolName: 'marksheet'
            },
            {
                toolName: 'minireset'
            },
            {
                toolName: 'jgthms'
            }
        ]
    },
    computed: {
        style: function () {
            var toolsList = this.tools;
            var toolNameStyle = '';

            for (var i = 0; i < toolsList.length; i++) {
                toolNameStyle = 'icon--' + toolsList[i].toolName;
                console.log('toolNameStyle: ' + toolNameStyle);

                return toolNameStyle;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: First of all, post an minimal example. This has nothing to do with Vue, you're returning toolsList[0] every time in style function. The execution will stop when you return a value.

Comment: There are many good examples for this case in the official documentation https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of computed property, simply do:

`<span :class="'panel-icon icon--' + tool.toolName">`

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. For some reason, I thought it was not possible to call tool.toolName inside the :class binding. I think I did try it, initially, but had the syntax wrong.